# How to print shortest String from ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

Ok so the goal is to print the smallest length string ( for example, if input is "co", "college", "colleges", "university"   I want it to print out co. 
I've tried the college.compareTo( ____ ); as well as a couple other things but I can't seem to get it to print it out. 
Also it isn't anything fancy (if you've read/have head first java 2nd edition then we are on chapters 5/6)
I'd rather if you can link me to a video that will show the process of what needs to be done with an explanation but anything is helpful :s been staring at this coding for a couple weeks and kinda went brain dead on it...
This is what I have so far (accepts strings from user);

```
ArrayList <String> colleges = new ArrayList <String> ( ) ;
    String input;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your college (Press Enter twice to quit) ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equals ("")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            colleges.add(input.toUpperCase () );
        }// end of if else statement
    }// end of while loop

    System.out.println("The following " + colleges.size() + " colleges have been entered:");

    for ( String college : colleges) {
         System.out.println("\n" + college );
         System.out.println("Character count: " +  college.length( ) );
    }// end of for each loop
```

Answer (score 4):

These are the steps you need:

1. Create a custom [`Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort strings based on their length.
2. Get the shortest string from your list by using your custom comparator with the [`Collections.min()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)) method.

In its most compact version, your code could look something like this (assuming there are no `null` strings in the list):

```
String shortest = Collections.min(colleges, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a clean and very understandable (good for code review) way and you'll rarely make mistakes.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Agreed. Not strictly needed. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic to print the smallest string in given arrayList

```
string smallString = "";
for ( String college : colleges) {
    if(smallString.length() == 0 && college.length() != 0)
    {
        smallString = college ;
    }
    else if(college.length() < smallString.length() && college.length() != 0)
    {
        smallString = college;
    }
}
println("Smallest string is: " + smallString );
```

Comment: I used length() for finding string length not for ArrayList.

Comment: Gotcha. The code in the question and in your answer has the for-loop backwards (should be `for (String college : colleges)`). I'll remove my comment.

Comment: wrong. it isnt stated, that the strings cannot be empty. so in this case your solution doesnt find the shortest string

Comment: @TerryStorm I cant get you. Can you be please clear about your case.

Comment: lol, nevermind. missed the "&& college.length() != 0" in the first if entirely. But even so, not the most intuitive implementation. Why not initialize with `null`? Would be way more readable/intuitive IMO, since you dont need all these college.length() queries. Next thing : the list could be empty. So you would return an invalid String. Depending on requirements this could be not as intended

Comment: @TerryStorm yes college.length() not necessary and may be a double check. If list is empty then we need to validate before start iterating and hence that would not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String SmallestString(ArrayList <String> collegeArray){
    String smallest = "";
    System.out.println("");
    for(String string :collegeArray){
        //if input-string is null or empty
        if(string == null || string.trim() == "" || string.trim().length()==0){
            System.out.println("Emtpy String Encountered");
            continue;
        }
        if(smallest == ""){
            smallest = string;
            continue;
        }
        if(string.length() < smallest.length()){
            smallest = string;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Call it with:
`System.out.println("\nSmallest String: " + SmallestString(colleges));`